# calling to settimeout recursively for multiple instances returns always the latest instance

Tags: javascript

i am trying to run the code below,

```
 var sampleObject= function(data){
      this._data=data;
    }
    sampleObject.prototype.test = function(){
        _this=this; 
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.info(_this._data);
            _this.test();
        },1000,this);
    }
    var sample1=new sampleObject(1);
    var sample2 =new sampleObject(2);
    sample1.test();
    sample2.test();
```

the problem is that the  returned output is 

`2
2
2
2`

but i want it to be 

`1
2
1
2`

the question is what am i doing worng

Comment: `_this = this;` should be `var _this = this` *EDIT: Corrected variable name.*

Comment: you meant var _this=this; it works thanks can you explain why?

Comment: Oh, I see, I used the wrong name. Yes, that's right. If you're not sure what `var` does, or what happens when you leave it off, consider running through some beginner materials.

Comment: can you explain why the var is needed? thanks

Comment: the `var` makes the variable local. Otherwise it is global and both instances reference the same variable..